# What can one do to keep OpenGL up to date?

Tags: api, opengl, glsl, upgrade, glew

While trying to create a program in **OpenGL** using new features it provides, like *vertex buffers objects*, I eventually ran into a problem: many new functions in **OpenGL API** are not supported on my system. These unsupported functions include functions like **glCreateShader**, **glDeleteShader** and **glGenBuffers**.

How can one keep OpenGL up to date? How can one upgrade it, how can one enable extensions/features? I'm running **Linux Mint 13 (Maya)** and I have used **GLEW** to enable *OpenGL extensions*. Albeit I use **Linux**, I hope answers would cover other platforms like **Windows** and **Mac** as well.

Comment: Buffer objects are *ten years old*. They are not a "new feature*. Overall, this question is too vaguely specified to be answered. What hardware are you using? What drivers are you using? And so forth.

Comment: FWIW, on OSX, you don't do anything to keep it up-to-date other than installing a newer OS. It's not updated separately from the OS, but minor updates (like from 10.8.2 to 10.8.3) will often contain bug fixes, and such. It's best to be on the latest version of the OS you can run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in this kind of scenario might be drivers, which are not up to date. There is also a chance that OpenGL context isn't correctly created before calling function **glewInit** to initialize **GLEW** and enable **OpenGL** extensions. This was the case here.